# Control flow in Play framework

Tags: routes, playframework

I have a form page. When the page is submitted, I want it to go to a central controller (instead of a form action value) which will get all the information (form action value, post values, get values), and I want to pass those values to another play application to process. Is that possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have to use an External LoadBalancer. 
The LoadBalancer will take the submitted form values and throw to the instance. The Instance will get the values and sent back the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You could try altering the action attribute of the form so it points to your central controller.  If the method you point to doesn't have any parameters, you'll need to extract them from the request yourself.

If you're using the #{form} tag, you'll need to switch to a regular HTML  element:

...

Comment: my problem is i have completed a whole project and i want to use the project in another play project(Load Balancer which will not redirect to the original page it just sends a request and gets the response. If form submitted it has to send back those infos to the same instance ) If i were changing like above. Then i need to change in all places. Is there anything which i can do mnimum changes for this thing to work